# div layout; sidebar movers after adding div to header

Tags: css, html

trying to get to grips with layouts I'm trying to get a full width header, inside the header is a left sidebar and a right sidebar. The body is divided into 5 sections full width, left and right sidebars, center content with 3 columns, the footer will be the same as the header. 
The sidebars are fixed width so the center content will compress or expand as per screen size.
I've tried many ways to achieve this, but failing dismally!
My best attempt is as follows, when i add the 'commented' code it adds the left header sidebar as i intended, but moves the left sidebar into the center section, where the left sidebar is supposed to be its now the center section.

I think I'm very close but missing something. can someone point me in the right direction please?

Html

```
<body> 
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <!--<div class="headerleft">
            <div class="headerleftcon">leftcon</div>
            </div>-->
        <div class="header-content">Header
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="body">body
        <div class="left-sidebar">
            <div class="left-content">left sidebar</div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-sidebar">
            <div class="right-content">right sidebar</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">Content
        <div class="left-col">
            <div class="left-colcontent">left col</div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-col">
            <div class="right-colcontent">right col</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer-content">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div> 
</body>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;}
.header, .footer{
 height: 80px;
 background-color: #EFEFEF;
 position: relative;}
.header-content{
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: center;}
/*.headerleft{
 height: 100%;
 background-color: red;
 width: 200px;
 float: left;}
.headerleftcon{
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}*/
.footer-content{
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: center;}
.container{
 height: 100%;}
.body{
 height: 100%;
 margin-top: -80px;
 margin-bottom: -80px;
 background-color: #C7DFFA;} 
.content{
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
.left-sidebar{
 height: 100%;
 background-color: gray;
 width: 200px;
 float: left;} 
.right-sidebar{
 height: 100%;
 background-color: gray;
 width: 200px;
 float: right;}
.right-col{
 height: 500px;
 background-color: blue;
 width: 150px;
 float: right;} 
.left-col{
 height:500px;
 background-color: blue;
 width: 150px;
 float: left;} 
.left-content{
 padding: 100px 10px 100px 10px;
 margin: }
.left-colcontent{
 padding: 100px 10px 100px 10px;} 
.right-content{
 padding: 100px 10px 100px 10px;
 text-align: right;}
.right-colcontent{
 padding: 100px 10px 100px 10px;
 text-align: right;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3yuJ/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ab2LT/

I am not sure if this is the result that you are expecting. I added a  `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after the end of the div header to clear the elements floated.

Comment: Yes, this works,thank you. I had tried adding clear both in the css and have just tried again in jsfiddle, this does not work. How can I get this result without including style in the htlm?

Comment: Ah, ok...I was adding clear both to the header elements, I added it to the left-sidebar and it works, thank you.

Comment: Answering your first question, you can create a css class with that property and add it to the div. <div class="cssclearclass">

Comment: sorry I have a 'bad' reputation evidently!